Should session be closed after each query in sqlalchemy?
I am using sqlalchemy orm query, I want to know if closing session after each query is really necessary?
def foo():
   session = get_orm_sqlalchemy_session()
   try:
      pass
   except Exception as ex:
      logging.error(str(ex), stack_info=traceback.print_exc())
   finally:
      session.close()


It is not really "necessary" but if you look at the SQLAlchemy documentation you will see that the recommended approach is to use a context manager to clearly delineate the scope of the session for the task(s) at hand: with get_orm_sqlalchemy_session() as session:

Closing the session after each query is a common practice to ensure that database connections are properly managed and resources are released.
There are several reasons why a session should be closed:

ensure that database connections are returned to the connection pool and resources are freed.
makes sure that all transactions are properly committed or rolled back, avoiding potenstial issues with lingering sessions
ensure that the application remains in a consistent state when a session is closed in case of exceptions

Note that: scoped_session of SQLAlchemy provides thread-local sessions, the framework can handle session lifecycle automatically.

Its not a must, you can find more information here, but if you do, you can read the code easier and its easier to understand what the program is actually doing in more complicated codes. ORM has some very useful tools available. I hope this helped!
